# How to display copy-paste like menu on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to display custom menu items similar to copy-paste menu item, is there any way I can do this?

[image: Missing Image]

Answer (score 3):

I never do this, but there is a sample code named '[CopyPasteTile](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CopyPasteTile/Introduction/Intro.html)'

It seems that the important point is the [`UIResponderStandardEditActions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html) protocol, and the [`- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction%3awithSender%3a) method of UIResponder

Comment: is there any specific reason why you never want to do this? Or is there and better way? I just curious.